# 7-Zip 7za Command Line Can't Find the Specified File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, zip, 7zip

I have C# program using 7za.exe to check a zip archive using the "l" command and then extract it using the "e" command. Information about 7-Zip command line can be found at: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

I can run the program from my desktop on the sever and it works great, however running it directly on the server it gives the following exception: "The system cannot find the file specified". I have verified that the file path is correct and is being passed to 7za.exe. I have attached 7za.exe as an Embedded Resource in my project and not sure why it can't find the files? Any ideas?  Thanks!

Here is the code I have to verify I can open the zip archive and mostly the same to unzip except the l is an e.

```
Process l = new Process();
l.StartInfo.FileName = "7za.exe";
l.StartInfo.Arguments = "l " + filePath[i];
l.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
l.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
l.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
l.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
l.Start(); // This is were it throuws the exception because it can't find the file.
// Do stuff to verify zip archive is not corrupt
l.WaitForExit();
```

Ex: filePath[i] = C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ZipFile.zip

Comment: Maybe it's not able to find `7za.exe`

Comment: That what I thought originally, but I believe it is stating it can't find the file meaning it found the 7za.exe

Comment: @buzzzzjay: manojlds is correct.  If you're getting an exception, then `7za.exe` wasn't found, so starting the program failed.  If `7za.exe` started successfully, you'd get error messages on stdout (which you've redirected) or stderr (which you haven't), but not an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "embedded resource" can only be used with the .NET resource API, it doesn't create individual files and can't be found by normal Windows functions, such as `CreateProcess` (which is what `Process.Start` uses).

Comment: How do would I attach the exe file so that my project can run it?

Comment: @buzz: Usually it's the responsibility of the setup program (installer) to copy supporting files into the program directory.  If you have a setup project, it probably has an option to install additional files.  If not, you can just copy it yourself.  Or you can use the resource API to make a copy of the resource on disk, but  you might have permissions problems when writing to that directory.

Comment: You are correct. It didn't copy the exe over. I copied it over and it works great. Thanks!